# Makefile: target match dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have a command in Makefile:

```
# just a list of all package names separated by newline:
# gomq/consumers/aaa
# gomq/rock
PKGS=$(shell go list ./...)

# Coverage output dirs: coverage/$PKG/coverage.out
COVPKGS=$(addsuffix /coverage.out,$(addprefix coverage/,$(PKGS)))

final-command: coverage/all.out
    some-commands

coverage/all.out: $(COVPKGS)
    echo "mode: set" >$@
    grep -hv "mode: set" $(wildcard $^) >>$@

coverage/gomq/consumers/%:
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @ go test -coverprofile $@ $(patsubst coverage/%/coverage.out,%,$@) -redisAddr=$(REDIS_SERVER)

coverage/gomq/%:
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @ go test -coverprofile $@ $(patsubst coverage/%/coverage.out,%,$@)
```

So I got a list of directories in `$(COVPKGS)`, and I want to pattern match the list against `coverage/gomq/consumers/%` and `coverage/gomq/%` to fire different commands for different directories.

I think Make figures out those dependencies and tries to match them to a target so `coverage/gomq/consumers/%` will match consumer targets and `coverage/gomq/%` will match the rest.

But when I run it, it can only match `coverage/gomq/whatever`, cannot match any further down the directory like `coverage/gomq/whatever/whatever` or `coverage/gomq/consumers/whatever`. So some packages deep down in the directory cannot be tested. Any way to correct it? Thanks.

Actually, if the directories already exists with files, and I run make again, the target will not be matched.

Comment: Either I don't understand what you are asking, or I cannot reproduce. http://pastebin.com/sJ5r08jj

Comment: @tripleee, yeah, your example works well.  But somehow  my code still cannot match all the patterns in `$(COVPKGS)`.  I need to figure out the reason...

Comment: @tripleee, I edited it.  Actually there's a `mkdir` in each target.  The first time I ran, everything is fine.  After the first run, `go test` will generate some output files for some of the packages. And those packages cannot be matched the next time I do not clean the `coverage directory`.  How can I just update the files instead of skip them?

Comment: Still not clear. Sounds like Make decides that there is no need to remake the files; indeed, because you declare no dependencies, it will never remake them unless they are missing.  If your test targets depend on the files that you are testing, that dependency needs to be declared.